# Data types in #define function-like macros

Tags: c, macros, int, c-preprocessor, primitive-types

I'm trying to make a macros that calculates 2 <sup>n</sup> and 2  <sup>n - 1</sup>. That would be:

```
#define b(n) (2 << (n))
#define a(n) ((b(n))-1)
```

However for some reason this cast it as `int`, but I'm willing to use `unsigned long int`. Does anyone know how to solve this? I have thought about using inline functions, however I don't fully grasp the difference between function-like macros and inline functions.

Comment: Don't you want `#define b(n) (1u << (n))`

Comment: change it to `#define b(n) (2ULL<<(n))`, that should make it a long long

Comment: @Roberto ... or `(((uintmax_t)1) << ((unsigned)(n)))`

Comment: @chux: Yes, and the 1 is correct, not the 2, you are right (1<<1==2)

Comment: Thanks to Brian for the edit!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OP wants `unsigned long int`, then use that type in your macro

```
#define b(n) (1UL<<((unsigned)(n)))
```

When OP used `(2 << (n))`, the result is type `int`, as `2` is an `int`.  Operator `<<` with an `int` and `unsigned` results in `int`.  Instead use `unsigned` throughout.

---

Further, to emulate `power(2,n)`, certainly the OP wanted to use `1` shifted left, rather than `2` shifted left.

Comment: Indeed adding UL solve the problem, In fact I was about to inform that I solve the issue casting (unsigned long int) infront of the 1